# middleware not working in laravel's lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2, lumen-5.3

I have just started learning lumen micro framework and having trouble as my middleware doesn't seem to work. here's my code.

```
//defined middleware in route
    $app->get('/hello/{name}', ['middleware' => 'shield','uses' => 'Sampcontroller@show']);

//registered middleware in app.php
     $app->routeMiddleware([
        'shield' => App\Http\Middleware\Agemiddleware::class,
    ]);
```

Here it is middleware code

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        if ($request->input('name') == "18") {
            echo "hate yew";
        }

        return $next($request); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to dd() instead of echo? Laravel may not present the echo output at the end of its life cycle.

Comment: You did try to actually call `/hello/18`?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is if the input field value is ''== 18'' then it should echo  something. but my code just ignoring the middleware!

Comment: @HudsonPereira what's dd()?  could you please explain?

Comment: `dd()` is a helper function provided by laravel. it means die dump. basically like `var_dump()`

Comment: It is blindly displaying what i have defined in my controller instead of going through the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Fix you class name (just for convention). AgeMiddleware (rename the file and the class).

Go to the **bootstrap/app.php** and register your route middleware

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
    'shield' => App\Http\Middleware\AgeMiddleware::class,
]);
```

Make sure you put this snippet above the **return** statement.

Hit **/hello/18**.

If this doesn't work, you probably have another route above this one getting **/home/something** get requests.